# Install multiple version of cocoa pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is it possible to install multiple versions of cocoa pods on the same machine ? I need one project to be build from cocoa pod 0.33 and another one from the latest version. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 26):

When you install new version of cocoapods, the old one is not removed unless you explicitly remove it with

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
```

and select the version to be removed.

You can use the old versions by giving version number in the command, surrounded by underscores, like this:

```
 pod _0.38.2_ install
```

Since November 11, 2016 the master repo is not compatible with the old version and unless you have updated your Podfile correctly (replaced `source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"`
 with `source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"` or just added the latter one) you will see an error when using 0.x version of cocoapods:

```
"[!] The master repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.38.2)"
```

Information on how and why is [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/).

Comment: Thanks, this is so much easier than trying to toggle the primary version!

Comment: quick script to use the same version as podfile.lock: https://gist.github.com/vilanovi/95b8c92016f1b9d8102cc8164b3e8750

Answer (score 9):

I've made a small list of commands to use multiple versions of cocoapods, all tested with osx sierra 12.1, xCode 8

- View all installed versions of cocoapods :

  `gem list --local | grep cocoapods`
- Install a specific version of cocoapods with gem

  `gem install cocoapods -v 0.33.0`
- Install pods with specific version of cocoapods (change to your wanted version):

  `pod _0.33.0_ install`

All versions of Cocoapods can be found [HERE](https://rubygems.org/gems/cocoapods/versions)

Comment: I've built an easy script that runs pod install reading the version of your Podfile.lock, installing cocoapods version if requried and then running pod install on that version: https://gist.github.com/vilanovi/95b8c92016f1b9d8102cc8164b3e8750

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is. But for different users. Build one from user 1  and other from user 2.

$ gem install cocoapods --user-install

Answer (score 3):

You can use bundler.  CocoaPods even recommends this from their [site](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html)

In the root of your project, include a Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cocoapods', '1.0.0'
```

You can customize the version of cocoapods used for each project in its local Gemfile.  To run, simply call your pod commands from bundler (after running "bundle install"):

```
bundle install
bundle exec pod install
bundle exec pod update
```